# Why is Sass turning a perfectly valid radial-gradient into an invalid one?

Tags: css, sass, gradient, radial-gradients

I've got a semi-circular radial-gradient working here: http://codepen.io/Inlesco/pen/bpgbKN?editors=1100

Gradient styles:

```css
.el:after {
    content: '\00a0';
    background: radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, red 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 70%);
    background-size: 100% 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

The pen uses CSS. However, if you set a CSS preprocessor (LESS/SASS), no gradient is created as, fe., Chrome marks it as invalid (seen when inspecting).

And if I place the same code (HTML / CSS from CodePen) to a local file (CSS in body `<style>`), no gradient is created either.

How come it works in web code editors like CodePen, but only without any CSS preprocessors? Is the output of them somehow different for radial-gradient?

When compiled with Sass (SCSS), I get the following result:

```
.el:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  background: radial-gradient(at 50% 0% at 50% 0%, #ff0000 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%);
  background-size: 100% 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine when I choose Less or Sass as the preprocessor, just not SCSS (latest version of Sass). You may need browser prefixes. See http://codepen.io/TylerH/pen/eZgYEK If you remove the `-moz-` prefix line from the mixin, it stops working in Firefox in SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sites like Codepen and Sassmeister don't compile with Sass, they compile with Compass (which is Sass with a bunch of extra stuff added to it).

Compass provides a function called `radial-gradient` (along with `linear-gradient`) that does a bunch of fancy stuff underneath the hood when combined with the background and background-image mixins to generate prefixes and inline SVGs for you.

Certain versions of Compass have a bug where they'll generate an invalid radial-gradient when you omit the optional shape argument.  You just need to add it:

```
.el:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 0%, #ff0000 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%);
  // ^ added `ellipse` here
  background-size: 100% 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1937

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for the explanation. I bet I should've searched Compass' github page before posting.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are declaring the LESS syntax in an incorrect manner. Try this,

```
.el {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 6em;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:30px;
   &::after {
      content: '\00a0';
      background: radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, red 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 70%);
      background-size: 100% 30px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      float:left;
      width:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe?  Either you know or you don't know.  Did you "try this"?  Did it work?

Comment: Yes. Since I don't have the LESS code that is used therefore used "Maybe". Yes I did try it in the codepen link and it did work. Else I wouldn't have given the solution without checking, right?

Comment: You do understand the question is specifically tagged Sass, right?  That the code in question also fails in LESS is an added bonus.  Your answer doesn't work when the preprocessor is set to Sass.

Comment: @PratikBasak Your code works with LESS, bu fails with SCSS. The snippet has no syntax differences in this case, but the output is different. Why?

I wanna believe SCSS does something differently.

Comment: I have mentioned the syntax is in LESS as mentioned in the description. In the question a codepen link has been shared. I have used that code and used LESS for the syntax. I will update the syntax for SCSS in a while.

Comment: @Denialos the syntax for targetting the siblings in SCSS is different. I will update my answer with the SCSS syntax in a while.

Comment: I do not know who down voted my answer, but for SCSS syntax I would recommend you to check my answer in SCSS compiler instead of codepen or sassmeister.

Comment: In other words, you don't know the answer.

Comment: I challenge you to run my code on a SCSS compiler. In the description it clearly states "The pen uses CSS. However, if you set a CSS preprocessor (LESS/SASS), no gradient is created as, fe., Chrome marks it as invalid (seen when inspecting)." I provided a answer for LESS syntax. As per my knowledge the SCSS syntax is the same as LESS atleast for this scenario.

Comment: The question is specifically asking about Codepen, not running code with the Sass compiler, and tagged [tag:sass], not [tag:less].  The OP *should* have provided an output to illustrate the problem, rather than using vague "the browser doesn't like it" descriptions.  If you don't know the answer to the question being asked, move on to the next question.  It's worth noting that the OP has updated their pen to contain the exact code you've provided and it *still does not work* when set to Sass (SCSS).

Comment: @cimmanon as you can see.. it has been stated "The pen uses CSS. However, if you set a CSS preprocessor (LESS/SASS), no gradient is created as, fe., Chrome marks it as invalid (seen when inspecting)." It says SASS/LESS. I gave the answer based on the LESS syntax which was mentioned was not working.

Comment: That's just it, you *didn't* provide an answer, you provided a codedump.  You don't show or explain what they did wrong or how it is any different than the code already provided.  In fact, I couldn't get the original code to fail as described when I switched the preprocessor to LESS.

Comment: Guess I did misinterpret the question. Anyways, @cimmanon thanks for the arguments. But I still find your replies harsh.